# How to avoid plotting for a whole script?

Tags: r

I'm on linux (LMDE).

I have this script that plots many stuff with the classical graphics and ggplot. Sometimes I also call `pdf()` or `png()`, but sometimes I just let the default grDevice pop up and display it for me (RStudioGD or x11())

The problem is that when I execute this script from Rscript with a different user (in my case, the apache www-data), it may raise permission problems, especially for the default device, when I have not preloaded any other device. (e.g.: `Error in (function (file = ifelse(onefile, "Rplots.pdf", "Rplot%03d.pdf"),  : 
  cannot open file 'Rplots.pdf'
Calls: source ... barplot -> barplot.default -> dev.hold ->`)

I would like to be able to just discard any of these plots (or even all plots) by just one or two lines at the beginning (and the end) of my script. Something like `nullDevice()` / script / `dev.off()` that will ensure that at least the default graphs are piped to something harmless.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen such a facility. What is generally done is to test for the conditions under which the code is running using the `interactive` function which returns TRUE  only when in an interactive session:

```
 if (interactive() ){  pdf("myPlot.pdf")
   plot(1:10)
   dev.off()        }

 ?Devices
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't really answer my question. I am looking for a way to do it without changing each line of plotting in the script.